# Extra variables on a custom 404 template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to be able to use **extra variables** on a **custom 404 template**.

```
#404.html
{{ extra_var }}
```

I have already tried:

```
#urls.py
from myproject.myapp import views
handler404 = views.handler404

#views.py
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django import http
def handler404(request):
    extra_var = 'my_extra_var'
    t = loader.get_template('404.html')
    return http.HttpResponseNotFound(t.render(RequestContext(request, 
      {'request_path': request.path, 'extra_var': extra_var, })))
```

However, it doesn't seem to work: I can only access to `request_path.`

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" is horrendously vague. What happens? Are you sure your `handler404` is being called? Can you access `request_path` in your template?

Comment: I can only access to `request_path`.

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG = True` in your settings?

Comment: No, I'm using `DEBUG = False`, otherwise I wouldn't be able to see my custom template.

Comment: Glad my answer worked for you - in future, don't mark things as community wiki unless they don't have a definite answer (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: @Paolo - not sure your context processor idea is the best way of dealing with this - since that'll add `my_extra_var` into the context of every template - is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you can access `request_path` but not `extra_var` suggests to me your view is not being called properly, since `request_path` is passed automatically to the `404.html` template, per the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view):

> If you don't define your own 404 view
>   -- and simply use the default, which is recommended -- you still have one
>   obligation: you must create a `404.html`
>   template in the root of your template
>   directory. The default 404 view will
>   use that template for all 404 errors.
>   The default 404 view will pass one
>   variable to the template:
>   `request_path`, which is the URL that
>   resulted in the 404.

I think you need to give `handler404` a string, rather than a module, like this:

```
handler404 = 'myproject.myapp.views.handler404'
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.

`handler404` should be set in the `urls.py` file, but you also have to import it, and that's not in the docs.

1. add `handler404` to your imports

   ```
   from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url, handler404
   ```
2. set `handler404="string.of.the.view.to.load"`

   ```
   handler404="myApp.views.pagenotfound"
   ```
3. define your 404 view in `view.py` as a usual view.

Comment: it will be good to have this in the docs , helps for newbies else a lot of time is wasted